# Async loop died! org.zeromq.ZMQException

Tags: apache-storm, topology, apache-zookeeper

i have this in worker log file , How can i solve it ?

```
[ERROR] Async loop died! org.zeromq.ZMQException:
Address already in use(0x62)
at org.zeromq.ZMQ$Socket.bind(Native Method)
at zilch.mq$bind.invoke(mq.clj:69)
at backtype.storm.messaging.zmq.ZMQContext.bind(zmq.clj:57)at backtype.storm.messaging.loader$launch_receive_thread_BANG_$fn__1629.invoke(loader.clj:26)
at backtype.storm.util$async_loop$fn__465.invoke(util.clj:375)
at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:24) at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

and supervisor

```
still hasn't start
```

spout in ui didn't `emit`

worker log file after executed the launch command

```
 ERROR] Error on initialization of server mk-worker
 java.io.IOException: No such file or directory
at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
at java.io.File.createNewFile(Unknown Source)
at backtype.storm.util$touch.invoke(util.clj:432)
at backtype.storm.daemon.worker$fn__4348$exec_fn__1228__auto____4349.invoke(worker.clj:331)
at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:185)
at clojure.lang.AFn.applyTo(AFn.java:151)
at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:601)
at backtype.storm.daemon.worker$fn__4348$mk_worker__4404.doInvoke(worker.clj:323)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:512)
at backtype.storm.daemon.worker$_main.invoke(worker.clj:433)
at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:172)
at clojure.lang.AFn.applyTo(AFn.java:151)
at backtype.storm.daemon.worker.main(Unknown Source)
 INFO] Halting process: ("Error on initialization")
```

this what happened after restart storm

```
1- i tried to kill the topology 
2- remove what storm-local folder contain
3- restart connect nimbus and supervisor
```

the result i have now

`1- some executors in nimbus not alive and trying to clean up the topology`

2- supervisor has this message

```
[ERROR] Error when processing event java.io.FileNotFoundException:
File does not exist: storm-local/workers/361c029c-b9c5-4ca7-    
 bced-f8ea084d45a3/heartbeats "/1444899266048
```

3- the worker log file

```
"worker 361c029c-b9c5-4ca7-bced-f8ea084d45a3 for storm topology name on  

 9d05b304-6bb5-497e-85b3-656eb82fb37e:6704 has finished loading 
 2015-10-15 10:50:46 executor [INFO] Deactivating spout spout0:(57) "
```

Comment: It seems that to port is not free. Make sure no other process/service uses the port or reconfigure Storm to use a different port.

Comment: Thanks for replying,i think you are right , i used another port for supervisor and tried to edit in file called vp4_ip_local_port , but supervisor still has this message "still hasn't start" but worker has this "worker 28b76eb7-e6de-4a2a-81ee-91c5716dd493 for storm topology name on 0950c07f-4b43-4e17-9b23-2b9c1b4b6c06:6703 has finished loading" !"  how can worker finished and topology submitted and supervisor still hasn't start ?

Comment: can you help on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33142241/storm-spout-didnt-emit-result-file-empty ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that to port is not free. Make sure no other process/service uses the port or reconfigure Storm to use a different port.

In order to change the port, you need to edit `conf/storm.yaml` file (best on each machine that runs a supervisor). Do compare with `defaults.yaml` in order to find the correct parameter name.

The second error seems to relate to the local Storm tmp directory. Try to shut down the cluster, clear this directory, and restart Storm.

Comment: but why supervisor still hasn't start ?

Comment: According to the error message supervisor tries to open an already occupied port. Thus it cannot start...

Comment: but how worker finished his work ? i'm sorry i didn't got it well

Comment: after executing command which launch between supervisor and worker i found in the worker log file what i will edit in the post now

Comment: It seems that Storm tries to resume an old topology. Did you make sure, that the topology is killed and cleaned up properly before stopping Storm? Maybe stopping Zookeeper and cleaning Zookeeper tmp directory can help to clean up old state...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92368/discussion-between-user3188912-and-matthias-j-sax).

Comment: I'm tying now to see if there are conflicts in the ports and i guess this is the last chance i have ! i hope i can solve it today

Comment: i hope you can send me your email to send you project and files , may you check it ? !