# storm spout didn't emit & result file empty

Tags: apache-storm, topology

i'm new to storm i submitted different topologies form github like storm-starter and others successfully after some problem i faced it but some of the some `spout didn't emit` ! like that 
[image]

is that right ? or is there a problem ?

where can i find the result after submitting topology ? 
i guessed in the `result` file in `storm` folder but it's empty !

this what i have in the bolt "one of them "
[image]
[image]

Comment: I cannot follow completely... For the result: does your sink bolt write to a file? If yes, this file will be located at the machine that executed the bolt (if you have multiple instances of the sink running on different machines, you will get multiple output files each containing one partition of the overall result). Check the UI to see on which machine the sink bolt instances got executed.

Comment: thanks for helping , i'm sorry as i'm new how can i checked it in UI ? i mean in which section ?

Comment: Click on the ID of the operator to get a more detailsed view for it.

Comment: i checked but didn't find and thing about machine i'll edit post to you

Comment: It all runs the the same machine called "ubuntu" as shown in the column "host".

Comment: i guessed that ubuntu is the host that in the file /etc/hosts because i had 127.0.0.1   localhost and 127.0.1.1 ubuntu do you mean that ?

Answer (score 1):

There is no explicit "result" file in storm. Your topology is responsible for handling/storing results wherever/whenever you need to. You can check the log files from each worker for logs (System.out calls or logger bindings) or you can have a sink bolt that writes whatever result you need locally to a file on the machine where it is being executed or you can have an hdfsBolt to write the results to an hdfs file or you can have an external server that receives results via sockets from your last bolt, etc...

The list is endless, it is up to you.

Comment: Thanks for replying ,i'm sorry for my questions , what i made with this project is that i ran it into eclipse and worked well with me but i should submit the topology of this project into storm after some errors i submitted as you can see from screenshots and what i get from using storm is that to deal with data in real time but until now i can't imagine that . NOW in this screenshots is that topology in the right way or not ? and WHY some zeros appeared !!?

Comment: what is the benefit from the result file in storm folder ?